# OnClick if statement only running once?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, onclick

I have an issue with an if statement that is being called when the user clicks on an element. Below is the code of said element:

```
<div id="dropdown" onclick="dropper()" class="YearEvents_2016">
    <h1>2016</h1>
</div>
```

the function "dropper()" code:

```
function dropper() {
var x = document.getElementById('dropdown');
var y = document.getElementById('YearEvents');

if (x.style.height === "14vh") {
    x.style.height = "75vh";
    y.style.height = "100vh";
} else {
    x.style.height = "14vh";
    y.style.height = "40vh";
}
```

}

When the user clicks the element, the code runs and the x and y variables are changed. However, upon clicking the element again (in order to reduce the x variable's height back down to 14 again) nothing happens, despite the else part of the statement depicting that something should happen.

Not sure if its something completely obvious; I'm not that advanced in Javascript. Any help as to why the function doesn't run again when the element is clicked on again, would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit** Similarly to the x height decrease (from the else statement), the y variable is also not decreasing in size. Is there a way to make both x and y's changes work in the same statement, and furthermore is there a way to delay the execution of the y decrease in order to make the x element reduce in size slightly before the y one does so? Thanks for the help one and all again.

TL;DR both elements x & y increase in size upon first run, then both x & y reduce in size upon second run, but with y reducing in size a little after x.

Answer (score 1):

When using an `if` statement you need to use two equals `==` (or three for strict equality `===`) to check if the left-hand side equals the right-hand side. At the moment you are assigning the variable a value, not checking equality. Thus, you need to change your `if` statement to the following:

```
if (x.style.height === "14vh") {
```

See working example below:

```js
function dropper() {
  var x = document.getElementById('dropdown');
  if (x.style.height === "14vh") {
    x.style.height = "75vh";
  } else {
    x.style.height = "14vh";
  }
}
```

```css
#dropdown {
  background: #FF0000;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 75vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropdown" onclick="dropper()" class="YearEvents_2016">
  <h1>2016</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. This part is working, however I have encountered another problem (I have updated the question to provide context) however, as I am also trying to reduce the y's height back down to 40vh in the else section, however similarly to my earlier problem, it isn't reducing in height. Perhaps a poor explanation, but I have updated the question to provide context. Thanks again